# How to set font for elements in FastReport.Web so that applies on pdf export?

Tags: .net-core, fonts, fastreport

I am using fast report web for my dotnet core application.I have a report that contains some elements.
**These elements use a special font that is not exists on client's device**.

**If i set font in designer , it will works only when that font installed on client's device.**

How can i set font for this elements , such that texts be correct in preview and pdf export?

Moreover i have printing problems such as separated characters and disordered numbers and letters in pdf and print.(My reports language is Persian and it is rtl)

My code is:

In controler :

```
var webReport = new WebReport();
webReport.Report.RegisterData(some_data, "Data");
var file = System.IO.Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "Reports\\" + model.File);
webReport.Report.Load(file);
return View(webReport);
```

In view:

```
<div id="printBody" style="width:100%">
    @await Model.Render()
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems currently , fastreport web doesn't support full features for printing and pdf exporting for rtl languages. So i did following scenario and i got acceptable result.

1 - Export report to image

2 - Convert prepared image to pdf using **iTextSharp**

3 - Return prepared pdf

By so there is no need to install font on client device.

I used following function:

```
public FileStreamResult ReportToPdf(WebReport rpt, IWebHostEnvironment _env)
    {

        rpt.Report.Prepare();
        using (ImageExport image = new ImageExport())
        {
            //Convert to image
            image.ImageFormat = ImageExportFormat.Jpeg;
            image.JpegQuality = 100; // quality
            image.Resolution = 250; // resolution 
            image.SeparateFiles = true;
            var fname = "";
            var no = new Random().Next(10, 90000000);
            fname = $"f_{DateTime.Now.Ticks}_{no}";
            rpt.Report.Export(image, _env.WebRootPath + "\\Exports\\" + fname + ".jpg");


            // Convert to pdf
            MemoryStream workStream = new MemoryStream();
            Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, workStream).CloseStream = false;
            document.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

            document.SetPageSize(PageSize.A4);
            document.Open();
            float documentWidth = document.PageSize.Width;
            float documentHeight = document.PageSize.Height;

            foreach (var path in image.GeneratedFiles)
            {
                var imagex = Image.GetInstance(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path));
                imagex.ScaleToFit(documentWidth, documentHeight);
                document.Add(imagex);

                try
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(path);
                }
                catch { }
            }
            document.Close();
            byte[] byteInfo = workStream.ToArray();
            workStream.Write(byteInfo, 0, byteInfo.Length);
            workStream.Position = 0;

            return new FileStreamResult(workStream, "application/pdf");
        }
    }
```